# Encrypting with specified options

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I am looking at the Python [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) package.

I really don't have much idea about how the encryption happens behind the scenes, or how the key is generated, but I am wondering if it is possible to specify options as to how the strings should be encrypted?

The main specification I want is for the encrypted string to only have alphanumeric characters. Also being able to set the maximum length would be preferred, but is not required.

Comment: A ciphertext is generally a sequence of bytes with values between 0 and 255. If you only want alphanumeric characters, you have to find a corresponding [binary to text encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding), e.g. hexadecimal or Base36 (the common Base64 uses besides alphanumeric characters also `=` for padding and depending on the variant `+`, `/` or `-`, `_`). The length of a ciphertext depends on the length of the plaintext, so that a maximum length generally can't be specified.

Comment: However, the various encodings have different efficiencies (= ration of input to output bytes), e.g. hexadecimal 50% and Base64 75%.